# How to use encoding in supercsv getHeader

Tags: java, supercsv

I'm using supercsv 2.1.0 to parse a CSV File with german words in it.

The given CSV file has a header at the first line.
In this header there are some mutated vowels like: Ä,ä, Ü,ö and so on.
For example:
Betrag;Währung;Info

In my coding I'm trying to get the header of the csv like this:

```
ICsvBeanReader inFile = new CsvBeanReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"), CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE);

final String[] header = inFile.getHeader(true);
```

Here is my problem with the header array.
All headers with mutated vowels are not encoded correctly using utf8 charset.

Is there a way how I can read the header correctly?

Here is a pseudo unit test:

```
public class TestSuperCSV {


@Test
public void test() {
    String path = "C:\\Umsatz.csv";
    File file = new File(path);

    try {
        ICsvBeanReader inFile = new CsvBeanReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"),
                CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE);
        final String[] header = inFile.getHeader(true);
        System.out.println(header[9]); //getting "W?hrung" but needed "Währung" here


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: Have you tried using `"UTF-8"` instead of `"UTF8"`?

Comment: No, "UTF-8" doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your file isn't actually using UTF-8 encoding.

I can replicate your scenario by creating the CSV file using ISO-8859-1 encoding and running your code, and it appears as `W?hrung`.

If I then update the `InputStreamReader` to use `"ISO-8859-1"` as the encoding, then it appears correctly as `Währung`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was my fault assuming the file was UTF-8 encoded, but ist was ISO-8859-1.

Comment: No worries :)  Don't forget to close the reader by the way (you can use try-with-resources as you're using Java 7).

Comment: same over here... assumed utf-8, and turns out the file is encoded ISO-8859-1